# What is wrong with this simple RelativeLayout Android program?

Tags: java, android, button, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I've created this very simple `RelativeLayout` as a test for something I may want to do later. Currently, there are just supposed to be 3 buttons, `second`, `alpha` and `mode` arranged relative to each other.

I have two issues: firstly, there is something wrong with the XML layout file and I have no idea what, as I've thoroughly checked through it. This leads to errors on lines 10 and 11 of the layout. Secondly, there is no generated `R` file as there usually is in an android activity. This leads to an error on line 11 of the main code, as it tries to call something from the R file.

My code is as follows:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/alpha"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mode"
        android:text="@string/second"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alpha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/second"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/alpha" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/second"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/mode" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main `Activity` code:

```
package com.example.TI84;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TI84GraphingCalculatorActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you should probably do some reading on the android developer site and understand how android projects work.

Answer (score 3):

RelativeLayouts, as the name might suggest, organize elements in a Relative manner. Therefore, you cannot make a reference to a widget that is lower in the file from one that is above it. This layout will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/alpha" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mode"
        android:text="@string/second" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alpha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mode"
        android:layout_below="@id/mode"
        android:text="@string/alpha" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You weren't getting an R.java because it is not generated when there are errors in your XML files.

Also, though you didn't ask for this, your original XML file had circular dependencies. This means that two of the widgets reference one another in such a way that they create an infinite loop, like A is to the left of B, B is to the right of A

Comment: Read this comment Maxim wrote on my answer: "I did and it works, I was wrong. Sorry, somehow was sure that it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

When your xml files contain errors, the R class won't get generated. Your error is this:

```
android:layout_above="@id/alpha"
```

Put:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/alpha"
```

Comment: This is wrong, @+id when you declare element android:id="@+id", when you use it later access to element without +

Comment: But if you reference it before it has been created, with "+" will create it, won't it? (at least that's my idea).

Comment: I think to create an element OS needs to know what to create (TextView, LinearLayout, ListView,... etc.) If you just write android:layout_above="@+id/alpha" expecting OS to create "alpha" element, how it can figure out what to create.

Comment: Nuno is right. You can reference an element that you will create afterwards.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't know what kind of element it is, and it'll allocate memory to do so if needed later. I'm just taking a hint. :) I was under the impression that was it, since I read on Pro Android 3 Book that the "+" will create the element if it doesn't already exist, this is explicit written for the creation of the element, not reference, but I guess we do it before). That's my idea. Anyway, we can always test it. :)

Comment: I did and it works, I was wrong. Sorry, somehow was sure that it doesn't work. However, regardless the fact that xml still valid, declaration should go first. In my test graphical builder changed after me id names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in line 10

```
android:layout_above="@+id/alpha"
```

and this in 11

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mode"
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have errors is because you are referencing ids which haven't been defined by that point in the file. You can only lay it out relative to ids which are defined above the element in the file.

There is no `R.java` file because the error in the XML file caused the build to fail, and the file is generated during the build.

Comment: This was it! I wasn't aware that the order of how buttons are declared in the layout mattered. Once I fixed this and did a quick project clean in eclipse, everything was working as expected. Thanks again.